# google map markers not loading in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-markers

I am using the google maps API.

The following is in the `<head>`

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

The following is in the `body`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        //size: new google.maps.Size(150,150)
        maxWidth: 500,
    });
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.90, -99.00),
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        var markers = [];


        for (var i = 0; i < businesses.length; i++) {

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(businesses[i].latitude, businesses[i].longitude);
            var marker = createMarker(latLng,businesses[i].name, businesses[i].description);

            markers.push(marker);


        }

    }

    function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
        var contentString = html;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
            });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var businesses = new Array();
</script>
```

I then run some php and have this within a php foreach statement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    business = {
        name:"<?php echo $i; ?> - Columbia Gorge Blue Grass",
        description:"<?php echo $row['display_name']; ?>",
        address:"$row['address'];",
        latitude:"<?php echo $row['lat']; ?>",
        longitude:"<?php echo $row['lon']; ?>",
        url:"$row['url'];",
        business_type:"Getaway"
    };
    businesses[<?php echo $i; ?>] = business;
</script>
```

After the foreach statement I have the `div` for the map and call the initialize statement

```
<div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
<script>    
    initialize();    
</script>
```

Everything works fin in Chrome and Firefox but in IE I get the "Done, but with errors on page." error. The map loads fine in IE but no markers appear on the map.

When I click on the IE error icon, this is the message I get:
    Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Fri, 13 Jan 2012 16:54:36 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 111102061
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://www.domain.com/contractor/listings
```

I'm pretty sure the problem occurs when `initialize();` is being called but I can't tell what is causing the issue.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

-Mike

Answer (score 1):

trailing comma here:

```
 maxWidth: 500,
```

Comment: Didn't fix it. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @bigmike7801 : Checked your Css Properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.  latitude and longitude are floating point numbers.  Not sure if you should be wrapping them in " " in that case.

```
latitude:"<?php echo $row['lat']; ?>",
longitude:"<?php echo $row['lon']; ?>",
```

Possibly IE is treating them as strings.  Another suggestion; remove this line and see if that makes any difference:

```
zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
```